# Pinescript V5 - If statement not working as expected

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

New to pinescript and I have some code that is not executing as I would expect it too. It is sending this alert every minute, and I do not believe it should.

```
if smaDiff > emaDiff + 1 and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("Sell", from_entry = "Buy")
    alert("SELL SIGNAL FOR BTC/USD (" + str.tostring(close) + ")", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

I have been reading the manuals, but thus far I have not found anything helps me with this issue.

Comment: can you please add the code for `smaDiff` and `emaDiff` cause I can not see what is in those variables. Otherwise I cant help you.

Comment: Sure 

smaShort = ta.sma(close, 5)
smaLong = ta.sma(close, 15)
emaFastLength = 5
emaSlowLength = 10
emaFast = ta.ema(close, emaFastLength)
emaSlow = ta.ema(close, emaSlowLength)

smaDiff = smaShort - smaLong
emaDiff = emaFast - emaSlow

Comment: please use the [Edit Button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77212683/edit) to update your post, so other people can see it too, and can give you a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `alert()` function will fire an alert whenever it is called.

You call this function when `smaDiff > emaDiff + 1 and strategy.position_size > 0` is `true`. Whether you exit a position is not relevant for this call.

It looks like you want to close a position conditionally. In that case, you need to use `strategy.close()` function.

You can also use the `alert_message()` argument of `strategy.exit()` or `strategy.close()`.

```
if smaDiff > emaDiff + 1 and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.close("Buy", alert_message="SELL SIGNAL FOR BTC/USD ({{close}})")
```

Comment: My main issue right now is this alert ALWAYS fires.... even when there has been no strategy. entry to buy a position. Thanks, for your example I will incorporate those changes.

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example so I can see what is happening.